# how to check if a unique value exists in db in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to save some data from an external source that has no id other than the data itself (eg. Red, Used, Volvo etc. from the ebay api).

So I have set up my tables like so:

```
aspectHeaders
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
name varchar(30)
UNIQUE KEY `NAME`(`name`)

aspects
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
name varchar(30)
aspectHeader_id INT
UNIQUE KEY `DETAIL` (`aspectHeader_id`,`name`)
```

aspectHeaders would contain:

```
7 Manufacturer
```

and aspects would contain:

```
1 Volvo 7
```

So in 2 stages I could check for the existence of any given data in either table and then insert it if it doesn't exist. But my question is can I do it in 1 stage? That is, is there code to check if the data exists and insert it if not and either way return the id?

Hope this is verbose enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If by "code" you mean a single MySQL statement, I don't think there is.  Or at least I don't think there is without making an overly-complicated multi-query query.

Just make an `alreadyExists()` method (or something) and check before insert - something like:

```
if(!$this->MyModel->alreadyExists($data)) {
    //do insert here
}
```

Comment: As with Mark's answer, I have +1 this as it is what I already thought but as its not the answer I can't tick it.

Comment: I believe it is the answer, unfortunately - the answer is that there isn't a MySQL query worth using that will do what you want.

Comment: By "code" I meant CakePHP code, as stated in the title, such as a built-in function.

Comment: @khany - the answer is still no :/

Comment: Just to qualify to anyone else reading this, I am not giving this answer as true because it began with 'If by "code" you mean a single MySQL statement...' which is not what I asked.

Comment: @khany - your question is "is there code to check if the data exists and insert it if not and either way return the id?"  With such a generic question, I'm not sure what you expect.  The answer is always "yes, you can write code for that... it might be 600 lines of code, but yes - you can".  I think it safe to assume that's not what you were looking for, so we have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a method like touch() for this that does all the magic internally.

```
// always returns id (or false on failure)
public function touch($data) {
    // check if it already exists
    if (exists) {
         // return id and do nothing
    }
    // create() and save()
    // return id or false if invalid data
}
```

Comment: I have +1 this as it is what I already thought but as its not the answer I can't tick it

Comment: A basic find(count) etc for example